# Is it possible to find out the users who have checked out my project on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm wondering if there is any way to know who has checked out my project hosted on GitHub? This would include people who have forked the project directly on GitHub, as well as people who may have cloned the repository using standard `git clone` commands.

Comment: I believe he means if someone does "git clone git://github.com/his/project.git".

Comment: okay, what about those who downloaded my projects? is it possible to know who they are?

Comment: From the privacy point-of-view: Hopefully this is _never_ possible.

Comment: You can view Number of clones and Unique Visitors in *Traffic* Tab under _Graphs_.

Comment: Once again, this is an old question, but it does appear quite a way up on the Google search. Github introduced clone graphs a time back, on the graphs page in a repo. You can check out more info here: https://github.com/blog/1873-clone-graphs

Answer (score 43):

If by "checked out" you mean people who have cloned your project, then no it is not possible. You don't even need to be a GitHub user to clone a repository, so it would be infeasible to track this.

Comment: That said, as Kashyap Prajapati points out in a comment on the original question, it *is* possible to track the *number* of clones.

Comment: it is possible to track

Comment: im sorry i meant views yea . not possible to see who viewed    https://github.com/{username}/{repo}/graphs/traffic

Answer (score 23):

### Use the GitHub Network Graph to Track Forks

You have no way to see who has checked out your repository using standard git commands such as `git clone`, but you *can* see who has forked your repository on GitHub using the [Network Graph Visualizer](https://github.com/blog/39-say-hello-to-the-network-graph-visualizer). At the time of this answer, you can access this feature in at least two ways:

1. From the "Network" tab just to the right of the "Code" tab on the navigation bar at the top of your repository.
2. By clicking on the numbers (if non-zero) in the call-out just to the right of the "Fork" widget on the right-hand side.

For example, here is a partial screenshot of the [rbenv network graph](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv/network):

[image: rbenv network graph]

The "Members" tab at the top of the Network Graph will also show you a different view, listing the names of the people who currently have forks on GitHub. It obviously will not show people who cloned outside of GitHub, or folks who have subsequently deleted their forks.

Answer (score 13):

I believe this is an old question, and the Traffic was introduced by Github in 2014. [Here is the link](https://github.com/blog/1672-introducing-github-traffic-analytics) to the description of Traffic, that tells you the views on your repositories.

Answer (score 9):

Let us say we have a project **social_login**. To check the traffic to your repo, you can go to: [https://github.com/{username}/social_login/graphs/traffic](https://github.com/%7Busername%7D/social_login/graphs/traffic)

---

- Example:-

  https://github.com/balireddypraveen/social_login/graphs/traffic

Answer (score 7):

Go to the traffic section inside graphs. Here you can find how many unique visitors you have. Other than this there is no other way to know who exactly viewed your account.

Answer (score 0):

In your repository, go to the `Insights` tab and then to the `traffic` section. You can see the number of visitors and clones made of your repository there.